# How do you extract a substring within column that contains people's Name & title that are in "Myles, Mr. Thomas Francis" format and only want "Mr."

Tags: python, string, dataframe, substring, extract

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x2ID.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdSLj.png)Want to add matched results as new column of dataframe within a python function

I tried using re.search() expression

```
for i in input_df["Name"]:
   Title[i] = re.search(".$",i)
```

I get Type_error and not sure how to write pattern to get desired result

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow:) Could you please share how your df looks like and what would be the desired output after you finish the extraction.

Comment: It may be more fail-safe (depending on the consistency of the names) to use a [list/dict of english titles/honorifics](https://gist.github.com/sole/10847831) instead of regex.

Comment: The one dataframe has column names "PassengerId Survived Pclass Name Sex Age SibSp Parch Ticket Fare Cabin Embarked" and I want to add another column Title to it that add the extracted "Mr.", "Miss." etc. from the Name column

Comment: It won't let me paste a snippet of dataframe unfortunately

Comment: Expected outputs
extract_title(train_df)['Title'].unique() == ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Master.',
                                              'Don.', 'Rev.', 'Dr.', 'Mme.','Ms.',
                                              'Major.', 'Lady.', 'Sir.', 'Mlle.',
                                              'Col.', 'Capt.','Countess.', 'Jonkheer.']


extract_title(test_df)['Title'].unique() == ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Master.', 
                                             'Ms.', 'Col.', 'Rev.', 'Dr.','Dona.']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `str.extract` here with the regex pattern `\b[A-Z][a-z]+\.`:

```py
input_df["Title"] = input_df["Name"].str.extract(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]+\.)')
```

For a more sophisticated option, you could also use `str.replace`:

```py
input_df["Title"] = input_df["Name"].str.replace(r'^.*,\s+|\s+.*$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks it kind of worked but the expected output is extract_title(train_df)['Title'].unique() == ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Master.',
                                              'Don.', 'Rev.', 'Dr.', 'Mme.','Ms.',
                                              'Major.', 'Lady.', 'Sir.', 'Mlle.',
                                              'Col.', 'Capt.','Countess.', 'Jonkheer.'] and i get array(['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Miss.', 'Master.', 'Don.', 'Rev.', 'Dr.', 'Mme.',
       'Ms.', 'Major.', 'Lady.', 'Sir.', 'Mlle.', 'Col.', 'Capt.', 'the',
       'Jonkheer.'], dtype=object)

Comment: 'the' should not be there in the list as well

Comment: With a minor tweak I got it too work with the first one you suggested. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

re.search returns a "match object" if a match is found, or `None` if no match is found. So you may want to do something like:

```
for i in input_df["Name"]:
    x = re.search("Mr[s]*\.",i)
    if x:
        Title[i] = (x.group())
```

Your code sets the value of Title[i] to a match object instead of a string, which is probably where the type error is coming from. Use the .group() method to return just the matching part of the string. Use the if statement to handle cases where no match was found.

As for the regex, I don't know what your data looks like exactly but you could try matching one more more capital letters, followed by zero or more lower case letters, followed by a period. Eg `re.search("[A-Z]+[a-z]*\.",i)`

Be warned regex can trip up over edge cases, so check carefully.

Comment: I don't just want to extract Mr. but all titles that ends with a fullstop from Column Name so not sure  x = re.search("Mr[s]*\.",i) would suffice